# Write values from a particular cell in an existing excel sheet in pandas version > 1.1.5

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, openpyxl

I had been using the following codes to write dataframe values in specific range of an existing excel spread sheet.

For example: My spreadsheet looks like below

```
         |  A  |  B   |  C  |  D  |  E  |
         |:----|:----:|:---:|:---:|----:|
         |     |Value:|     |     |     |
```

My code is as below:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Data':[10,20,30]})

from openpyxl import load_workbook
writer = pd.ExcelWriter("book1.xlsx", engine='openpyxl',index=False,mode='a')
book = load_workbook("book1.xlsx")
writer.book = book
writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets)
df1.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='MySheet1',index=False,header=None,startcol=2,startrow=1)
writer.save()
```

This was working until I had pandas version 1.1.5. I just got pandas upgraded to 1.3.1 and now I get the following error.

---

File "C:\Users\Username\Anaconda3\envs\envname\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel_openpyxl.py", line 437, in write_cells
f"Sheet '{sheet_name}' already exists and "

ValueError: Sheet 'MySheet1' already exists and if_sheet_exists is set to 'error'.

---

If I pass parameter if_sheet_exists='replace', it replaces the sheet.

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter("book1.xlsx", engine='openpyxl',index=False,mode='a',if_sheet_exists='replace')
```

I want to retain the original sheet with its other content and format and only to place the dataframe values to the specified location onwards. One option I see is to downgrade pandas to 1.1.5 (*though I have not tried and I'm assuming panda upgrade is causing this issue*)

Can someone help me on this please?

Comment: For this kind of control, you might want to do everything directly in openpyxl

Comment: I have downgraded pandas to 1.1.5 and now this works fine